# MySQL store float

Tags: mysql

I am trying to save a float in my MySQL database as a decimal(20,10). But I don't think this is a good way, because when I try to save 2.14 it will save 2.1400000000.

At least this one is better than float(20,10) because that one was rounding it wrong.
But which type should I use to store it as 2.14? I can't just say 20,2 because sometimes I have for example 34.2222291 as value.

SOLUTION:
double(20,10) fixed it.

Comment: What's wrong with 2.1400000000?

Comment: If I have more than 2 decimals the users will know that the value was calculated and not measured. At the moment they can't see whether the value was calculated or measured.

Comment: Remember to add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `2.14` and `2.1400000000` is just an issue of output formatting (in whatever language you use for that - but even possible with MySQL [if you will](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)).

So if you want *exact* decimal values, `DECIMAL(20,10)` is the way to go. `DOUBLE` (double precision floating point) just has less rounding problems than `FLOAT` (single precision floating point), it does not eliminate them because it is still a floating point type.

Comment: I'm sorry to see this answer un-accepted. Did you understand why `DOUBLE` does not *fix* your problem, just hides it for the moment? If something was not clear, please tell me. But if you just don't care, that's okay too.